# tesseract_versionnumbers.vsprops missing when trying to build the base API example for Tesseract OCR

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tesseract

I'm trying to build [VC++ 2008 example of tesseract-ocr API](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-API-Example-vs2008.zip), but even loading the project in VS 2008 fails with this error:

```
Property sheet file '..\..\include\tesseract_versionnumbers.vsprops' was not found or failed to load.
```

This file is referenced in the *.vcproj file:

```
InheritedPropertySheets="..\..\include\tesseract_versionnumbers.vsprops"
```

I've already compiled tesseract-3.01 with VS 2008, but I can't find this file anywhere in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the folder `APIExample` inside `vs2008` directory.
The file  `tesseract_versionnumbers.vsprops` located in `vs2008\include` directory.

Good luck!